# How to apply spring security oauth 1.0 to sepcific URLs

Tags: oauth, spring-security

I have a project which has some controllers as well as a list of REST APIs(starting with url '/api/') in the same project. Now I have to apply spring security oauth to only the REST APIs. I couldn't find any documentation on applying the same. Is there any built-in functionality in spring security oauth or should we go for some kind of filter that would filter oauth requests and return some possible error codes for URLs(controller urls and others) other than the REST APIs(/api/) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is dedicated [OAuth project](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security-oauth) for spring security. You can apply it only to some URLs using multiple **http** config elements. It may looks like this:

```
  <!-- REST API -->
  <http pattern="/api/**">
    ....
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ProviderFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    ....
  </http>

  <http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none"/>

  <!-- Additional filter chain for normal users -->
  <http>
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
    <form-login .../>
  </http>

  <oauth:resource-server id="oauth2ProviderFilter" .../>
```

Comment: Hi Maksym, Thank you very much for your answer. As I am relatively new to this, I am not able to find out exactly what this "oauth2ProviderFilter" refer to. Could you please spare your time to explain it in detail?

Comment: You can prepare an instance of corresponding filter using **resource-server** tag from oauth namespace. Tell me if you have some another question.

Comment: Thank you Maksym for your kind replies. I actually want to implement OAuth 1.0a, but I guess the above mentioned code is for OAuth2.0. I am trying with two http elements as you have mentioned. But please do provide your support if possible with a sample configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out 1.0a version of OAuth. Could you use OAuth2.0?

Comment: I wish I could, but my project requires OAuth1.0a configuration. A thought comes up to my mind Maksym. what if we configure the "OAuthProviderProcessingFilter" manually in "web.xml" for only specific urls? My guess is it might work. But I still want to do it in spring's way(using "oauth:provider" tag in spring config)... Any thoughts?

Comment: I am do not know how to do it in spring's way for your case. The idea of using "OAuthProviderProcessingFilter" manually looks promising for me. Try it.

Comment: Thanks Maksym. Right now I got around that issue by customizing OAuthProviderProcessingFilter and applying it manually. And it doesn't full OAuth Protocol right now. Becuase it doesn't provide ways to request for request token and access token. I provided an interface for the user to generate their access token and the secret manually.